# WEMOS D1 R1 Interrupt repeats continuously, when triggered, Is it bouncing? How to fix it?

Tags: arduino, interrupts, esp8266, debounce, gpio-external-interrupt

I am having such a nightmare to make it work, I am using a WEMOS D1R1 to handle the movement of an encoder via external interrupts.

Instead if detecting the edge (L to H), it detects the status, so the interrupt function repeats continuously if the state is H, so its behaving like a  ***while(state==H){...}***, instead of triggering once per H to L .

Here is my code so far:

```
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR ISRC();
void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  pinMode(D9,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(D8, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D8), ISRC, RISING);  
  Serial.println("Started"); 
} 

void loop() 
{} 

//This function is supposed to get executed when interrupt happens, instead it happens looply while D8 is HIGH
 void ISRC() { 
 Serial.println("Interrupt Detected"); 
}
```

I dont know what else to try here is what the monitor says, please, note the time marks:

*20:41:49.935 -> Interrupt Detected*

*20:41:49.935 -> Interrupt Detected*

*20:41:49.935 -> Interrupt Detected*

*[...]*

I have readed here that setting the input as ***INPUT_PULLUP*** fixes the issue, but it didnt happen with me.

I had tried wiring the interrupt input (D8), to a "clean" source, as it is the ***BUILTIN_LED*** (D9) pin, and then it does work perfectly.

The problem comes when I connect it to the encoder or a button.

I guess its a bouncing problem...

How can I avoid this supposed bouncing?

Is it really a bouncing problem?

How can I make it work?

Thanks everyoune in advance.

Here is a pic of the encoder schematic, i just added a pullup resistor to the Output (O) [image]

Here is a link to the datasheet
https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/000/EE-SX460-P1-pdf.php

Comment: How is the encoder wired? What type of output? Open drain or is it something else? Please add a schematic and a link to the encoder.

Comment: Serial.Println within an interrupt routine is BAD NEWS! Defer printing to a loop in the main process (or another task if you're using an RTOS) and use a shared variable (e.g. boolean) set in the ISR to tell the latter to print.

Comment: Thanks for your attention lads, the encoder is a EE-SX460-P1, I updated the post with its schematics and added a link to the datasheet. And well the printing was just to show in the forum, but i did make a counter and print from the loop but, got the same effect.

Comment: You cannot use Serial in an interrupt! It is too slow and can lead to unpredictable results. You can blink a led, set a volitale varable or something else fast however in no way use Serial and it's output functions. You need to understand interrupts before using it, read some documentation first,

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hardware problem for which you would need an oscilloscope to track down. Also check whether interrupts are available for D8 on your particular Arduino:
[attachInterrupt()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/)

## Software Oscilloscope for Arduino

You could try using the Arduino as a software oscilloscope to see if the input is bouncing by taking a rapid sequence of samples and sending them to the serial port, something like this:

```c
const int BUTTON_PIN = 2;

const int NUM_SAMPLES = 512;
int samples[NUM_SAMPLES];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("\n\nInitialising...");

  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  
  // Clear the samples array.
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    samples[i] = 0;
  }
  
  Serial.println("Finished setup.");
}

void loop()
{
  static int sample_i = 0;
  static int total_i = 0;
  if (sample_i == NUM_SAMPLES)
  {
    // Write the samples to the serial port.
    char str[24];
    for (sample_i = 0; sample_i < NUM_SAMPLES; sample_i++)
    {
      sprintf(str, "%10d: %10d\n\0", total_i++, samples[sample_i]);
      Serial.print(str);
    }
    sample_i = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    // Read the next sample.
    samples[sample_i++] = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
  }
}
```

## Debounce a Button using Hysteresis for Arduino

You could also see if it's possible to debounce the button using a polling technique without interrupts. If this technique doesn't work, it points to a hardware problem.

This Arduino code uses a polling technique to debounce the button using hysteresis. The LED shows the state of the button. To avoid wasting processor time and power, the code only writes to the LED output pin upon a successful debounce. To ensure that an accurate time stamp is obtained when reading the button, it temporarily disables interrupts before reading the button and the timer, then enables interrupts again.

```c
#include <util/atomic.h>

class Debouncer
{
private:
  int input_pin;
  bool output_state;
  bool rise;
  bool fall;
  unsigned long debounce_delay_ms;
  unsigned long last_ms;

public:

  Debouncer(const int input_pin, const unsigned long debounce_delay_ms = 50)
  {
    this->input_pin = input_pin;
    this->debounce_delay_ms = debounce_delay_ms;
    this->output_state = false;
  }

  bool Output() const { return output_state; }
  bool Rise() const { return rise; }
  bool Fall() const { return fall; }

  bool IsDebounced()
  {
    bool input_state;
    unsigned long current_ms;
    
    // Temporarily disable interrupts to ensure an accurate time stamp for the sample.
    ATOMIC_BLOCK( ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE )
    {
      input_state = digitalRead(input_pin);  // No interrupt will occur between here...
      current_ms = millis();                 // ...and here, ensuring an accurate time stamp for the sample.
    }

    rise = fall = false;

    // Hysteresis:
    //   If there is no change, reset the debounce timer.
    //   Else, compare the time difference with the debounce delay.
    if (input_state == output_state)
    {
      last_ms = current_ms;
    }
    else if ((current_ms - last_ms) >= debounce_delay_ms)
    {
      // Successfully debounced, so update the outputs.
      rise = input_state && !output_state;
      fall = !input_state && output_state;
      output_state = input_state;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};

const int BUTTON_PIN = 2;  // Pushbutton pin number.
const int LED_PIN = 13;    // LED pin number.
const unsigned long DEBOUNCE_DELAY_ms = 50;  // The debounce time in milliseconds.

void setup()
{
  // Set pin modes.
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  static Debouncer button_debouncer(BUTTON_PIN, DEBOUNCE_DELAY_ms);
  static bool led_state = false;

  if (button_debouncer.IsDebounced())
  {
    // Update the LED to show the debounced signal.
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, button_debouncer.Output());

    // Alternative feedback: Toggle the LED on the rising edge of the debounced signal.
    /**
    if (button_debouncer.Rise())
    {
      led_state = !led_state;
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, led_state);
    }
    /**/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also build a Low Pass Filter to filter out the bouncing. This would only work for the button tho.
[image]